# How to use field_info_instance?

Tags: 7, entities

I am currently working with an Entity Reference field in Drupal 7, and I need to alter the results using `field_info_instance`. The field type is Entity Reference. Below are the steps I've taken:

```
$field_instance = field_info_instance('node', 'field_branch_vod', 'employee');
kpr($field_instance);
```

Could you please provide guidance on how to use `field_info_instance` to effectively alter the field results for an Entity Reference field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of those bits of information relate to the instance, they relate to the field itself (regardless of what it's attached to).

As such you need to use [`field_info_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7.x) to get them:

```
$field_info = field_info_field('field_branch_vod');
$target_type = $field_info['settings']['target_type'];
$target_bundles = $field_info['settings']['handler_settings']['target_bundles'];
```